# airtable get запрос

Tags: c#, .net, api

Всем доброго времени суток. Стоит задача:
"извлечь данные из airtable и положить в listview WPF C#".
Столкнулся с проблемой подачи get запроса в Аиртейбл. Нашел библиотеку, которая работает в airtable, но банально не могу понять синтаксис. Помогите пожалуйста.
ссылка на вики библиотеки (не реклама)
https://github.com/ngocnicholas/airtable.net/wiki/Documentation

код:

```
 const string baseId = "123";
    const string appKey = "123";

    List<string> fields = new List<string>() { "data1", 
                                                "data2"
};


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PrimaryTable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async void PrimaryTable_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string offset = null;
        string errorMessage = null;
        var records = new List<AirtableRecord>();



        using (AirtableBase airtableBase = new AirtableBase(appKey, baseId))
        {
            //
            // Use 'offset' and 'pageSize' to specify the records that you want
            // to retrieve.
            // Only use a 'do while' loop if you want to get multiple pages
            // of records.
            //
        
            do
            {
                Task<AirtableListRecordsResponse> task = airtableBase.ListRecords(
                       "TotalTable",
                       "testOFFSET",
                       fields,
                       null,
                       20,
                       100,
                       null,
                       "Grid");


                AirtableListRecordsResponse response = await task;

                if (response.Success)
                {
                    records.AddRange(response.Records.ToList());
                    PrimaryTable primaryTable = new PrimaryTable();
                    primaryTable.data1 = 1010101011;
                    primaryTable.data2 = "DS";
                    PrimaryTableView.Items.Add(primaryTable);

                    offset = response.Offset;
                }
                else if (response.AirtableApiError is AirtableApiException)
                {
                    errorMessage = response.AirtableApiError.ErrorMessage;
                    PrimaryTable primaryTable = new PrimaryTable();
                    primaryTable.data1 = 88888;
                    PrimaryTableView.Items.Add(primaryTable);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    errorMessage = "Unknown error";
                    PrimaryTable primaryTable = new PrimaryTable();
                    primaryTable.data1 = 11111;
                    PrimaryTableView.Items.Add(primaryTable);
                    break;
                }

            } while (offset != null);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
        {
            PrimaryTable primaryTable = new PrimaryTable();
            primaryTable.data1 = 13;
        }
        else
        {
            PrimaryTable primaryTable = new PrimaryTable();
            primaryTable.data1 = 13;
            // Do something with the retrieved 'records' and the 'offset'
            // for the next page of the record list.
        }

    }
```

Comment: В WPF не работают с контролами напрямую в код-бихайнде окна, там пишут код только для изменения поведения контролов, в особо страшных случаях. Во всех остальных случаях используются привязки данных `Binding` и шаблон проектирвоания MVVM. Это не winforms. А так, если мне память не изменяет, то надо `<имя_контрола>.ItemsSource = <ваш_список>`.

Comment: так я и не работаю там. код кинул для примера запроса и все. у меня всё работает кроме самого запроса на аиртейбл